# Why I am getting only the 1st and last adapter Position's Database ID Correctly?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have set an intent from HomeFragment Card Click to redirect to Second Activity. Also, I am sending the current position's Database ID from the recyclerView Adapter.

But in the Second Activity, only the 1st and Last items ID are received correctly. If i click on 3rd position item, then some other position's ID is send to Second Activity.

Here is my Code :

```
 public class HomeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    List<HomeModel> homeModelList;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    List<String> keysList;

    String keyID;

    public HomeAdapter(Context context, List<HomeModel> homeModelList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.homeModelList = homeModelList;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_news, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        final HomeModel homeModel = homeModelList.get(position);
        holder.timesAgo.setText(homeModel.getTimesAgo().trim());
        holder.newsTitleTextView.setText(homeModel.getNewsTitle().trim());
        holder.newsDetailTextView.setText(homeModel.getNewsDetail().trim());

        Log.e("View counts ", String.valueOf(homeModel.getViewCounts()));

        holder.view_counter.setText(String.valueOf(homeModel.getViewCounts()));


        Glide.with(context).load(homeModel.getNewsImage()).centerCrop().into(holder.newsThumbnailImageView);//set error and placeholder


        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("News");
//        final String z = databaseReference.child(String.valueOf(homeModelList.get(position))).getKey();

//        Toast.makeText(context, z, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        keysList = new ArrayList<>();
        databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Log.e("Position is ", String.valueOf(childSnapshot.getKey()));
                    keysList.add(childSnapshot.getKey());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String pos = keysList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                Log.e("current Position is", pos);
                Toast.makeText(context, keysList.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailNews.class);
                intent.putExtra("currentPosition", pos);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

How can this Issue be Solved ? Please Guide me .

Comment: If you found my answer correct can i ask you to click the tick on the left hand side of the answer to say it's correct. For more information on what to do when someone answers your question click here: stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Change the following code:

```
 databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Log.e("Position is ", String.valueOf(childSnapshot.getKey()));
                    keysList.add(childSnapshot.getKey());
                }
            holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String pos = keysList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                Log.e("current Position is", pos);
                Toast.makeText(context, keysList.get(position), 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailNews.class);
                intent.putExtra("currentPosition", pos);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```